# A way to detect if a service is being uninstalled

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, service, topshelf

I have a service I created with TopShelf and there is a BeforeUninstall event which runs some code before the service is uninstalled, but this only runs if the user uninstalls the service through cmd, but if the user uses `Remove-Service` from powershell the event is not fired.

So my question is, is there any way to fire an event when a service is uninstalled regardless from where the user uninstalls it?

p.s. the reason I need this before uninstall event is because some other services are dependent on this service and they have to be stopped before the serivce is  uninstalled.

Comment: Does `Remove-Service` log an eventid in eventvwr

Comment: Why not simply do a [`Get-Service` <name>](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) to see if it removed?

Comment: Set a scheduled task to run when the event viewer logs the uninstall.

Comment: @iRon I need a task to run before the uninstallation process begins, because some other services are dependant on this service and they have to be stopped before the uninstall

Comment: @Scepticalistthat is to late because I need to run some code before the uninstall process

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in the event viewer for Event ID 1034 OR 11724(software package is removed successfully)?
Alternatively, you can run sc query [servicename].
Result 1060 will indicate the service does not exist.